# Yii2 Редактирование характеристик товара

Tags: php, yii2, crud

Есть 2 таблицы product и detail_value

В product содержатся товары, в detail_value - характеристики к этим товарам. Таблицы связаны между собой по полю id_product

Для работы с этими базами я использовал CRUD.

Чтобы вывести характеристики определенного товара я прописал связи в моделях и выводил, через обычный foreach, но как сделать добавление, редактирование и удаление? Кто-то сталкивался с подобным, буду рад любой помощи?

Comment: Так если вы правильно использовали CRUD, то там уже это реализовано. CRUD расшифровывается как Create, Read, Update и Delete

Comment: Вы не поняли суть, ну да ладно, я его уже решил